# Emacs search all buffer non-interactively

Tags: emacs

I currently have the following function:

```
(defun goto-python-class (classname)
  (interactive "sClass name: ")
  (search-forward (concat "class " classname)))
```

I am trying to find a search function that will search both forward or backward. Basically, search the entire buffer. There doesn't seem to be any. Is there any other way of doing so, without having to figure out if search succeeded or not, and attempt the backward search?

Comment: Does `occur` or `grep` do what you need?

Comment: If you add `(goto-char (point-min))` before `search-forward` it will search from the start of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally done like this:

```cl
(defun goto-python-class (classname)
  (interactive "sClass name: ")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (unless (re-search-forward
           (concat "class " classname)
           nil t)
    (message "Class %S not found" classname)))
```